# EntityFrameworkCore and code first with Sqlite including multiple navigation

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-standard

back in vs2015 i used an external program to create / modify my database and update it in vs with the ef designer.
It is also possible with vs2017 to use the designer with some third party tools, but i want to switch to code first. in this context i want to switch my class library to .net standard.

But i have trouble to get my databases working.
Here is an example, what i see when i open the edmx file.

[image: DesignerLayout]

The ID is not incremented, it is provided by an external service. every user of the service has an unique id and i store it there.

---

And now my (very simple) code first models:

```
    public class Users {
         public int UserID { get; set; }
         public string Name { get; set; }

         public Currency Currency { get; set; }
         public TimeWatched TimeWatched { get; set; }
    }

    public class Currency {
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public int CurrencyValue { get; set; }

        public Users Users { get; set; }
    }

    public class TimeWatched {
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public long Time { get; set; }

        public Users Users { get; set; }
    }
```

My DbContext looks like this:

```
     using Microsoft.Data.Sqlite;
     using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

    public class context : DbContext {

    public DbSet<Users> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Currency> Currency { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TimeWatched> TimeWatched { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) {
        var connectionStringBuilder = new SqliteConnectionStringBuilder { DataSource = "test.db" };
        var connectionString = connectionStringBuilder.ToString();
        var connection = new SqliteConnection(connectionString);

        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(connection);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Users>()
            .HasKey(c => c.UserID);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Users>()
            .Property(c => c.UserID)
            .ValueGeneratedNever();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Users>()
            .HasOne(a => a.Currency)
            .WithOne(b => b.Users)
            .HasForeignKey<Currency>(b => b.UserID);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Users>()
            .HasOne(a => a.TimeWatched)
            .WithOne(b => b.Users)
            .HasForeignKey<TimeWatched>(b => b.UserID);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Currency>()
            .HasKey(k => k.UserID);

        modelBuilder.Entity<TimeWatched>()
            .HasKey(k => k.UserID);
    }
}
```

---

It test it like this:

```
            using(var context = new testStandard.context()) {

            context.Database.EnsureCreated();

            var user = new Users {
                Name = "test",
                TwitchUser = 123456,
                Currency = new Currency {
                    TwitchUser = 123456,
                    CurrencyValue = 999
                },
                TimeWatched = new TimeWatched {
                    TwitchUser = 123456,
                    Time = 500
                }
            };

            context.Users.Add(user);

            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        using(var context = new context()) {
            var user = context.Users.First();
            // Currency and TimeWatched are always null
        }
```

I dont know why currency and timewatched are always null. 
what do i wrong?

Comment: At what point are currency and timewatched null? One of the things that EF Core doesn't do (because so many people do it wrong) is automatic hydration of navigation properties (or as it's more widely know: lazy loading). Again, this is because it's often used incorrectly and causes rather large and inefficient SQL to be generated. I would take a look at this article for more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Jamie!
I found a solution:

```
using(var context = new context()) {
var user = context.Users
            .Include(c => c.Currency)
            .Include(tw => tw.TimeWatched)
            .First();
}
```